# Multi series,multi-Yaxis Dynamic flot

Tags: jquery, flot

I am working on a chart using flot with multi-Yaxis and dynamic series. Here is a sample of what i am trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/4Emr9/3/. Now, the question is, How do i add a y-axis dynamically. In the example, the series is written 4 times and specified 4 times in the yaxes.

```
var data = [
{ data: generate(0, 10, function (x) { return Math.sqrt(x)}), xaxis: 1, yaxis:1 },
{ data: generate(0, 10, function (x) { return Math.sin(x)}), xaxis: 1, yaxis:2 },
{ data: generate(0, 10, function (x) { return Math.cos(x)}), xaxis: 1, yaxis:3 },
{ data: generate(0, 10, function (x) { return Math.tan(x)}), xaxis: 1, yaxis: 4 }
```

];

```
yaxes: [ { position: 'left', labelWidth : 18},
         { position: 'right', tickColor:'black', labelWidth : 18, tickDecimals: 0},
         { position: 'right' , tickColor:'black', labelWidth : 18, tickDecimals: 0},
         { position: 'right', tickColor:'black', labelWidth : 18}
       ],
```

I have a dynamic number of series to plot, and my code is something like this.

```
data.push({ label: selectedItem, data: dataPoints });
$.plot(placeholder, data, options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an `options` object and a `data` object, just add to both of them dynamically as you go:

```
options.yaxes = [];
for (var i=1; i<dataSets.length;i++){
    data.push({ label: selectedItem, data: dataSets[i], yaxis:i });
    options.yaxes.push({ position: 'right', tickColor:'black', labelWidth : 18, tickDecimals: 0});
}
```

This imagines that your source data comes as an array of arrays of points called `dataSets` that looks something like this:

```
dataSets = [
    [[0,1],[1,2],...],
    [[0,5],[1,1],...],
    //etc
];
```

Comment: what about the yaxis in options? should i put a dynamic yaxis in there? yaxes: [ { position: 'left'}] to be... yaxes: anArrayOfYAxis

Comment: ok.. this setup works for me.. I just dont set the yaxes in the options and the code like --->   data.push({ label: selectedItem, data: dataPoints, index: data.length + 1, yaxis:data.length +1 })  thanks Ryley